# SSH Keys Not Recognized?

Tags: debian, ssh, permissions, openssh, key-authentication

I have two Debian (11 and 12) systems. I'm trying to verify ssh access from server A to server B via keys, following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vINn1MIrf7o. I try to use the keys, however, it continues to ask for a password

Server A: Key gen and Permission verification

```
$ ssh-keygen -a ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -C "email@address"
$ ssh-copy-id USERNAME-B@SERVER-B

$ cat /home/USERNAME-A/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub 
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIAnsoixDlpGFTrBRfoV+flboh7rIFvAphI6xRe4G+3HO email@address

$ ls -l /home/USERNAME-A/.ssh
total 16
-rw------- 1 USERNAME-A USERNAME-A 111 Sep 25 16:51 authorized_keys
-rwx------ 1 USERNAME-A USERNAME-A 411 Sep 25 00:48 id_ed25519
-rwx------ 1 USERNAME-A USERNAME-A  97 Sep 25 00:48 id_ed25519.pub
-rwx------ 1 USERNAME-A USERNAME-A 444 Sep 25 16:05 known_hosts
```

Server B: Key and Permission verification

```
$ cat /home/USERNAME-B/.ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIAnsoixDlpGFTrBRfoV+flboh7rIFvAphI6xRe4G+3HO email@address


$ ls -l /home/USERNAME-B/.ssh/
total 12
-rw------- 1 USERNAME-B USERNAME-B 214 Sep 25 16:52 authorized_keys
-rwx------ 1 USERNAME-B USERNAME-B  97 Sep 25 15:16 id_ed25519.pub
-rwx------ 1 USERNAME-B USERNAME-B 142 Sep 25 00:38 known_hosts.old
```

Server A: SSH to server B

```
$ ssh -v USERNAME-B@SERVER-B
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.98 [192.168.0.98] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.98:22 as 'internalrouter01'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jsyFKXsTm5jC6GpM49Z9NdZTqaynwadcD80118n8/ck
debug1: Host '192.168.0.98' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:3fj8TFQ7RMRBsWyjPvTUYQWGvhMcmEGxM/9Bh5hCIdE
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:3fj8TFQ7RMRBsWyjPvTUYQWGvhMcmEGxM/9Bh5hCIdE
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I can not figure out what I need to do specifically to make this configuration work. Let me know if you have any tips. I tried researching, speculated permission issue, but i dont think thats the case, and nothing especially pops out to me, but then again im new to debugging ssh in general

**EDIT1**: (not renaming servers anymore to USERNAME-B, etc.)

Reply to roaima

```
$ ls -ld / /home /home/USERNAME-B/ /home/USERNAME-B/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 18 root             root             4096 Sep 22 15:42 /
drwxr-xr-x  4 root             root             4096 Sep 22 23:03 /home
drwx------  4 USERNAME-B USERNAME-B 4096 Sep 24 21:54 /home/USERNAME-B/
drwx------  2 USERNAME-B USERNAME-B 4096 Sep 25 16:32 /home/USERNAME-B/.ssh
```

Reply to Gilles Quénot

updated the permissions as requested, no effect

```
root@home-ok-ir01p:/home/internalrouter01# chmod 700 /home/internalrouter01/.ssh/
root@home-ok-ir01p:/home/internalrouter01# chmod 600 /home/internalrouter01/.ssh/*
root@home-ok-ir01p:/home/internalrouter01# ls -ld / /home /home/internalrouter01/ /home/internalrouter01/.ssh
drwxr-xr-x 18 root             root             4096 Sep 22 15:42 /
drwxr-xr-x  4 root             root             4096 Sep 22 23:03 /home
drwx------  4 internalrouter01 internalrouter01 4096 Sep 24 21:54 /home/internalrouter01/
drwx------  2 internalrouter01 internalrouter01 4096 Sep 25 16:32 /home/internalrouter01/.ssh
```

My ssh config

```
root@HomeNAS:/home/homenas# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Here are the most recent `sshd` entries from `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
root@home-ok-ir01p:/home/internalrouter01# tail -40 /var/log/auth.log | grep ssh
2023-09-25T17:31:38.020752-05:00 home-ok-ir01p sshd[8418]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
2023-09-25T18:05:45.894039-05:00 home-ok-ir01p sshd[11468]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 192.168.0.109 port 49624
2023-09-25T19:13:37.747404-05:00 home-ok-ir01p sshd[12124]: Connection closed by authenticating user internalrouter01 192.168.0.109 port 36860 [preauth]
2023-09-25T19:26:50.115306-05:00 home-ok-ir01p sshd[12253]: Connection closed by authenticating user internalrouter01 192.168.0.109 port 33018 [preauth]
```

Here's my server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

`chmod` the permissions

Client returns

```
root@home-ok-ir01p:/home/internalrouter01# env | grep '^SSH'
SSH_CONNECTION=10.7.0.2 35516 192.168.0.98 22
SSH_CLIENT=10.7.0.2 35516 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
```

Currently there are no changes to `ssh -v ROUTER-B@192.168.0.98`, except the change to no longer allow passwords (`PasswordAuthentication no`)

Comment: On server B, `ls -ld / /home /home/USERNAME-B /home/USERNAME-B/.ssh` added to your question please

Comment: Why public keys have e`x`ecution bit? You need `chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 600 .ssh/*` and we need you to share your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` without the comments and not as a comment, but by editing your post to add this really important information

Comment: Also on server B, look at the messages reported by `sshd` in `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: @roaima

made edits to the post hopefully showing what you guys asked for

Comment: @GillesQuénot

Made the edits to the post

Comment: Although you show us `/home/USERNAME-A/.ssh` for apparently an ordinary user on A, your `ssh` command on A is accessing `/root/.ssh` indicating it was run as root. You need to create the key for (under the homedir of) the same user you run `ssh` as.

Comment: You say, "_My `ssh` config_" but then you show the `sshd` config. If this is for the client, please instead show the `ssh` config (`~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`). If it's for the server you show this later on in the question anyway

root@HomeNAS:/home/homenas# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config